# Как написать метод обновления полей базы данных?

Tags: php, mysql, ооп

Пытаюсь написать  свой метод обновления полей базы данных. Столкнулся с проблемой формирования запроса. В данный момент придумал вот такое решение, но есть проблема с расстановкой запятых в запросе. Ну и вообще, может это можно написать гораздо проще, а я изобретаю велосипед?

```
 public function update()
    {
        $sql = 'UPDATE ' . static::$table . ' SET ';
        $fields = get_object_vars($this);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
            if ($name == 'id') {
                continue;
            }
            $sql = $sql . $name . '=:' . $name . ' ';
            $data[$name] = $value;
        }
        $sql = $sql . 'WHERE id = ' . $this->id;
        $db = new Db();
        $db->execute($sql, $data);
    }
```

Comment: Можно, конечно, отслеживать количество элементов в массива `fields`, и не ставить запятую после последнего элемента. Но может всё таки есть решение проще и лаконичнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неясно что внутри класса `Db` - pdo или mysqli, но проблему можно решить так например:

```
$fields = ['field1 = :field1', 'field2 = :field2', 'field3 = :field3'];
echo implode(', ', $fields);
```

Альтернативный синтаксис плейсхолдеров позволяет использовать `?` и передавать массив данных сразу в метод `execute`:

```
$fields = ['field1 = ?', 'field2 = ?', 'field3 = ?'];
echo implode(', ', $fields);
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот моя реализация этой обертки, возможно вам пригодится

```
/**
 * Edit the data in database
 * @param string $table
 * @param array $fields
 * @param string $where
 * @param array $params
 * @return int
 */
public function Update($table,array $fields, $where , $params = [] ){
    $sets = [];
    foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $sets[] = "$key = :$key";
        if ($value === null) {
            $fields[$key] = 'NULL';
        }
    }
    $sets_s = implode(',' , $sets);
    try{
        $query = "UPDATE $table SET $sets_s WHERE $where";
        $q = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
        $q->execute(array_merge($fields,$params));
    }catch(\PDOException $e){
        die('Error executing query ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
    return $q->rowCount();
}
```

где $fields это массив входных данных к примеру `'name' => $_POST['name']`, а $params это к примеру `$id` для `WHERE`, а переменная $where выглядит примерно так `"id_article = :id"`